# Pyspark dataframe is changed while the 'write' function usage

Tags: python, pyspark

This is a real mystery for me: when I try to write a pyspark df into Azure dataframe using jdbc, I run into a strange situation. While running the 'write' function my table is changed somehow without any reason, and sends to Azure wrong data. Afterwards it saves my pyspark df with the same wrong data. Here is a part of code I have written:

```
print(sparkDF_cleaned.show())
sparkDF_cleaned.write \
            .format("jdbc") \
            .mode("overwrite")
            .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
            .option("dbtable", "dbo.upsert_test") \
            .option("user", jdbcUsername) \
            .option("password", jdbcPassword) \
            .save() 
print(f"data loaded to table {db_table_name}")
print(sparkDF_cleaned.show())
```

Output is next:

```
sparkDF_cleaned : 
+------------+---+-----+----------+----------------------+
|     id_date| id|value|     _date|datetime_of_extraction|
+------------+---+-----+----------+----------------------+
|1 2022-05-01|  1|   17|2022-05-01|            2022-06-01|
|1 2022-05-06|  1|    6|2022-05-06|            2022-06-13|
|2 2022-05-02|  2|   10|2022-05-02|            2022-06-01|
|3 2022-05-03|  3|   15|2022-05-03|            2022-06-01|
+------------+---+-----+----------+----------------------+

data loaded to table upsert_test

sparkDF_cleaned : 
+------------+---+-----+----------+----------------------+
|     id_date| id|value|     _date|datetime_of_extraction|
+------------+---+-----+----------+----------------------+
|1 2022-05-06|  1|    6|2022-05-06|            2022-06-13|
|2 2022-05-02|  2|    5|2022-05-02|            2022-06-13|
+------------+---+-----+----------+----------------------+
```

Azure table recieves the data as it is in the second table. Dear colleges, why does it happen?
Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: i think data is written correctly. you cannot check written data by printing df after writing . You should go check data on source.

Comment: @AtlasBravoos it is same in the source. I mean same incorrect as in the second table

Comment: are you using something deterministic?  limit, sample, rand etc?
in those cases every calculation of the df may return different results.

Comment: @walking no, I do not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't still avoid the problem when using pyspark jdbc overwrite with pyspark transformed table.

Hovewer, I have decided to write pyspark table to local file, read saved data from the file and than post the data using the pyspark jdbc overwrite function.

It does not seem to be the best solution, hovewer, it works. If there will be better solutions, will be happy to read.

```
path = "*DataBricksWorkspace*/temp_table.json"
    dbutils.fs.rm(path, True)
    sparkDF.write.json(path) 

    sparkDF_copy = spark.read.json(file)

    sparkDF_copy.write.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl,
                           table=db_table_name,
                           mode="overwrite",
                           properties=connectionProperties)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite a late response, but there is no other thread mentioning this and we have encountered the same problem and deep dived into what is causing this and how to solve it the most efficient way.

We figured that the problem appears when reading from a sql db using a jdbc connection  and afterwards writing to the same sql db (possibly this problem can also be caused in a combination of different methods). The mutation to the database are applied to the dataframe before uploading. Thus, when appending data to the sql db the data is appended to the pyspark dataframe and the the write happens after. Which is an undesired effect because you add the data twice to db. similarly, when overwriting it will delete the pyspark dataframe and then upload an empty pyspark dataframe resulting to an empty db. Even more funky things happen when you have mutation between this read and write as these mutations happen to the df twice during the write.

Anyway, why this happen remains a bit of a mystery. But we suspect that this is a combination between pyspark multicore processing, pyspark method of lazy evaluation and the double connection to the same sql db (because of the read and write).

So to solve this you have to somehow disconnect the reference from the read dataframe from the dataframe you are writing, causing the lazy evaluation to go all the way back. Your method works as it completely blocks pyspark from understanding how this dataframe you are trying to write points back from the dataframe you tried to read. Another method that works is transforming the pyspark df to pandas and transferring back.

The easiest and efficient way we solved this is using both .persist() and .count(). The first caching the dataframe from that point forward and the second triggering an action so that pyspark is forced to do calculations on the dataframe. We took these two as we think they are the least computational intensive.